# Xcode - DatePicker: Show ONLY date string to a label

Tags: ios, string, datepicker

I have an app that has a textField that, when pressed, open a datePicker for the user to select the date and then send this information to a label. I need to get only the DATE value, but the string being sent is something like:

```
<UITextField: 0x7ff66e740bf0; frame = (16 12; 289 30); text = '08/03/2017'; opaque = NO; (...and so on...)
```

How can I get ONLY the DATE string?

my code is:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
{
datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
[self.dia2 setInputView:datePicker];

UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Pronto" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(ShowSelectedDate)];
UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space,doneBtn, nil]];
[self.dia2 setInputAccessoryView:toolBar];
}

-(void)ShowSelectedDate
{  
NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
self.dia2.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
mostraData.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _dia2];
[self.dia2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: You are setting just the date to `self.dia2.text`. But then you convert the `UITextField` (`_dia2`) to a string and assign that to `mostraData.text`. Why?

Comment: FYI - your date format is wrong. You want `@"dd/MM/yyyy"`. Never use `YYYY`. Use `yyyy` for the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mostraData.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _dia2];
```

is assigning the description of you text view to the label, rather than the formatted string that you just added to the text view.

```
mostraData.text = _dia2.text;
```

Comment: What's the point of using `stringWithFormat:` in the correct solution? And why directly access the ivar instead of using the property?